# Apache point to backend code hosted on an another box

Tags: python, apache

I am trying to volunteer a Python app project for my colleague who is on vacation due to some urgency. He has developed / hosted an incomplete app on another box over our office network. Now that I am trying to analysis I want to add some debug statement but hate to play with original code as there are hundreds of lines of code.  However I have the list of modules required by the backend app. Installing these modules locally in my box is failing constantly due to some issue.

However I have Apache setup at my local box. Is it possible that after copying the code to a separate location on the another box I can point Apache from my box point to the code in new location [remember it would be in another box]

To illustrate my local box IP is say A.B.C.D and the other box IP is X.Y.Z.A

Both are accessible to me. The code is in box having IP X.Y.Z.A say at /x/tool/test

I would copy the entire folder /x/tool/test to say /x/tool/test-my and now setup my Apache at IP A.B.C.D to point to app at X.Y.Z.A /x/tool/test-my path?

Is the same possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive? You can use it to point a local URI to a remote URL. Example:

```
ProxyPass /x/tool/text http://X.Y.Z.A/x/tool/test-my
ProxyPassReverse /x/tool/text http://X.Y.Z.A/x/tool/test-my
```

(The `ProxyPassReverse` may not be necessary). Also if cookies are being used and the cookie domain needs to be translated, you can use `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` and `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` to fix that.

Note that you do not need to turn on `ProxyRequests`. This is for **forward** proxies, not reverse proxies. It will turn your apache webserver into an open proxy.